# Do I have to use UTL_FILE.FCLOSE at catching exception as in other programming languages?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Do I have to use UTL_FILE.FCLOSE at catching exception as in other programming languages?

I'm using Oracle 11gR2:

Example code:

```
DECLARE 
  V1 VARCHAR2(32767) := 'This is a test'; 
  F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
BEGIN 
  F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MYDIR','MYFILE','w',256); 
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE_NCHAR(F1,V1); 
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1); 
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F1) THEN
         UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
     END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Entering an exception block does not automatically close files for you so, yes, you need to do this. Is this a problem?

Comment: I simply asked a question because on many sites/tutorials authors forget about closing handlers. When You post this as an aswer I will aprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FCLOSE_ALL` in the exception. This will ensure that all the opened file handles as part of the session gets closed when an exception is raised.